# How is "erogenous" incorrectly formed?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, prefixes, compounds, greek

When I check the etymology of *erogenous* in *[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/64070?redirectedFrom=erogenous#eid)*, it is mentioned that it is incorrectly formed (along with *erogenic*).

Etymology of *erogenous* from OED:

> formed as *erogenic adj.* + *-ous suffix*. 
> <sub>Both words are incorrectly formed.</sub>

Etymology of *erogenic* from OED:

> < Greek *ἔρως* sexual love + -genic *comb. form*: after French *érogénique*.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=erogenous&searchmode=none) explains as below:

> "inducing erotic sensation or sexual desire," 1889, from Greek *eros* "sexual love" (see *Eros*) + *-genous* "producing." A slightly earlier variant was *erogenic* (1887), from French *érogénique*.

---

I thought it might be something to do with the suffixes *-genous* and *-ous*, but the usage of them makes sense unless I'm missing something.

> **-genous:** word-forming element meaning "generating, producing, yielding;" see *-gen* + *-ous*. In modern formations, making adjectives corresponding to words in *-gen*.
>
> **-ous:** word-forming element making adjectives from nouns, meaning "having, full of, having to do with, doing, inclined to," from Old French *-ous, -eux*, from Latin *-osus*
>
> **-genic:** word-forming element meaning "producing, pertaining to generation;" see *-gen* + *-ic*.
>
> [[Etymonline]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-genous&allowed_in_frame=0)

*Etymonline* mentions as *inducing erotic sensation* but it doesn't seem like a big leap if we say *producing erotic sensation* because of the suffix *-genous*. Although, it might require stimulation as the phrase *erogenous zone* suggests.

Additionally, another similar word *indigenous* is directly from Latin but it is formed with the suffix *-ous* also.

> late Latin *indigenus* born in a country, native ( < *indigena* a native: see *indigene* *adj.* and *n.*) + *-ous* suffix. [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/94474?redirectedFrom=indigenous#eid)

After all, I'm still not sure why *erogenous* and *erogenic* are mentioned as incorrectly formed. Is it related to the suffixes or the early usage of the word?

<sub>We also have *érogénique* in French and *erógeno* in Spanish. Are they incorrectly formed also?</sub>

Comment: They may believe that joining a *Greek* root to a *Latin/French* suffix is incorrect.

Comment: @Peter - they might though it doesn't mean it is incorrect as there are plenty of words formed that way. "Television" for one =)

Comment: @Ermanen. I have just checked what Etymology.com had t say on this.
Here is what it says "A slightly earlier variant was erogenic (1887), from French érogénique. Both, as OED laments, are improperly formed."
In my opinion it says that both "erogenic" and "érogénique" are improperly formed while "erogenous" is correct.  At least it could be understood this way.

Comment: Rey says _érotogène_ only has the sense of aphrodisiac, whereas _erogène_ has the "zone" has you mention and the meaning you refer to. He also lists _érotologie_, _érotologue_, and _érotomanie/érotomane_ (and the _érotomaniaque_ archaic variant). Référence to erôtikos from erôs, erôtos as per answer.

Comment: Perhaps linguists are too embarrassed to be pedantic about these words when they were first used.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The stem of the Greek noun *erôs* "love, desire" is normally *erôt-*, not *er-*. So it should be **erotogenic** or **erotogenous** in English. Cf. *phôs, phôt-* "light", as in *photograph*, not **phograph*; *erotic*, not **eric*.

That said, there are forms in Greek that use *erô-* and *era-* as stems, like the verb *eraô/erô*, "I love". It's just that *er(a)-* is the ultimate root of all these words, but the stem of the noun is normally *erôt-*. Ancient Greek has many dialects and oddities, and some writers even use *erô-* as the stem of the noun in certain forms. So perhaps *erogenous* is defensible, but it's not standard Attic, so it is not the way a normal formation of a Latin or modern word based on Greek is supposed to go.

Comment: Awesome, now go back to your position to defend Hell!

Comment: I took the liberty of getting rid of the possible reading that every word in the world stems from the root _ἐρ-_. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Hah, writing that, I knew some OCD person would be unable to control himself...

Comment: Who are you calling CDO? I’m not CDO!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Um, mixing up letters, that must be a different disorder...

Comment: Tut tut! CDO—in alphabetical order, the way it's supposed to be, silly!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Err, all right, if that alleviates the throbbing pain in your brain stem, then CDO it is.

Comment: @PierreArlaud: Thank you! My main function is stopping souls from escaping the underworld, though...

Comment: @Cerberus Damn that sounds so much more erotogenous already!

Comment: @PierreArlaud: Mmm from the look on their faces, I'd rather say phobogenous...

Comment: Interestingly, there are also cases of the "reverse" "error," such as the "t" in "egotism" (although the variant "egoism" exists) and "chaotic."

Comment: @sumelic: Good examples! Might the -t- be a specifically French insertion?

Comment: @Cerberus: The same phenomenon of t-insertion does occur in French, but I'm not sure if it's always the source of this kind of "t" in English. The OED indicates "chaotic" was derived in English from "chaos," and its earliest citation is from 1713; the [cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/chaotique) says French "chaotique" is first attested around 1838

Comment: @sumelic: Right, I wouldn't know either. But I do believe *égotisme* or the like is older than English? The t in chaotic is also (almost?) universal in European languages, but I have no idea who was first, then, if it wasn't French, nor Greek...